# how to play video in asp.net with Google Youtube API and capture the onStatusChange event?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, youtube

I have 2 questions

1.I just want to know how to embed the youtube video in asp.net website with Google Youtube .Net Library?

2.when a user clicks on the play button on the youtube player, I want this action could fire a event which enables me to send a email to somebody.

If anyone could demonstrate the code and explaination, I would highly appreciate that :)

Thanks in advance.

Winston

Comment: I have inplimented the something similar using javascript Youtube api. [link](http://www.manishojha.com) .. let me know if you need anything else...

Comment: @manish, thanks :)although I have finished it, but thanks a lot man ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me. After more than 1 year, when I saw this question hasn't been answered by anyone.
I decided to write down my solution, hopefully it would be helpful.

1. Import the Google Youtube player

> ```
>  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

1. Add the js code

   ```
      google.load("swfobject", "2.1");

       function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
           document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
       }

       // Loads the selected video into the player.
       function loadVideo() {
           var selectBox = document.getElementById("videoSelection");
           var videoID = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value

           if (ytplayer) {
               ytplayer.cueVideoById(videoID);

           }
       }

       // This function is called when an error is thrown by the player
       function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
           alert("An error occured of type:" + errorCode);
       }

       var target = "";

       // This function is automatically called by the player once it loads
       function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {

           ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
           ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
           ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange","onPlayStateChange");

           target = document.forms[0].target;

       }



       //unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5)
       var n = 0;
       function onPlayStateChange(newState) {

           if (newState == 1) {

               document.forms[0].elements["Send"].value = "1";
               document.forms[0].target = "SendFrame";
               document.forms[0].submit();
               updateHTML("counter", ++n);
           }
           else {
               document.forms[0].elements["Send"].value = "0";
               document.forms[0].target = target;
           }           
       }

       // The "main method" . Called when someone clicks "Run".
       function loadPlayer() {
           // The video to load
           var videoID = "ylLzyHk54Z0"
           // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
           var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
           // The element id of the Flash embed
           var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
           // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
           swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID +
                          "&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1",
                          "videoDiv", "480", "295", "8", null, null, params, atts);
       }
       function _run() {
           loadPlayer();
       }
       google.setOnLoadCallback(_run);


   </script>
   ```
2. Add 2 div elements in the html code, one for player, one for counter

   ```
   <div id="videoDiv">Load...</div>"    
   <div id="counter">0</div>
   ```

Okay, that's all you need to do :)